# Properties of the first syzygy over Dedekind domains

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, dedekind-domain

Let $L$ be a Dedekind domain and $I = (a) + (b)$ a non-principal proper ideal in $L$. Consider equation of the form $xa + yb = 0$. Is it true that then there exists a proper ideal $J$ such that any $x, y$ that satisfy the equation belong in $J$?

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Is it clear to you that such a proper ideal does not exist if $I$ is principal? If yes, can you reduce to that case by localizing?

Comment: Well, looks like I just found a counterexample to that logic, Mohan. For $I = (5, 2\sqrt{-5})$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ the equation seems to imply that $x, y \in (\sqrt{-5})$. Unless I made a mistake somewhere in calculations. Could you please expand a little on your logic? Maybe I'm missing something... Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M\subset L$ be any maximal ideal. We will show that there exists $x,y\in L$ with $xa+yb=0$ and $(x,y)$ is not contained in $M$, which will show that no such proper ideal $J$ as in your question exists.

If you localize at $M$, then $L_M$ is a pid and thus $(a,b)$ is principal, generated by either $a$ or $b$. Wlog, assume $a$ generates it and then $b=pa$ for some $p\in L_M$, which we can write as $pa-b=0$. Now, we can find $s\not\in M$ such that $sp=q\in L$ and we get an equation, $qa-sb=0$. Since $s\not\in M$, we have proved our claim.

Comment: Mohan, I understand now. Makes total sense and thank you. I also realized now that I formulated the initial question incorrectly. I'm wondering rather if the equation implies that $x$ and $y$ belong to some maximal ideal $M_{x,y}$? ($M_{x,y}$ has to depend on $x, y$, as you have just demonstrated).

Comment: ...in other words, can $x$ and $y$ be selected in such a way that $(x, y) = L$?

Comment: @UnrealVillager You can easily check that if there are $x,y$ with $xa+yb=0$ and $(x,y)=L$, then $(a,b)$ is principal by using the relation $px+qy=1$ for some $p,q\in L$.

Comment: Ok, that's because in that case both $a$ and $b$ sit in $(aq-bp)$. Got it. Thanks a lot for your help with this today, Mohan.